# Analytic functions converge uniformly has same number of zeroes after a certain index

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n:D\to\mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on the open unit disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$.

Assume that there exists $f$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on any compact subset of $D$.

True or false: There exists $N>0$ such that $f_n$ has the same number of zeroes (counting multiplicities) for $n\geq N$.

Thanks for any help.

---

My attempt: First of all, I noticed some similarity with this question [Sequence of analytic functions and the limit function has same number of zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903617/sequence-of-analytic-functions-and-the-limit-function-has-same-number-of-zeros).

However, there seems to be two critical differences: our question is asking whether $f_n$ has same number of zeroes after $n\geq N$, which is different from whether $f_n$ has same number of zeroes as $f$. Also, we don't have the essential assumption that $f$ has no zeroes on the boundary.

I am also aware of this counterexample, where $f_n(z)=z-1+\frac 1n$ (exactly one zero on $D$) converges to $f(z)=z-1$ (no zeroes on $D$).

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a counterexample using the [Blaschke Product](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Blaschke_product).  Basically, given a sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{D}$ which approaches the boundary fast enough so that $\sum |1-|a_n||$  converges, you can construct a uniformly convergent infinite product such that the $N$th partial product has zeros $a_1,\dots,a_N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a counterexample:

Let $f_n=\begin{cases}
\frac 1n&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
0&\text{if $n$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
$

Then $f_n\to 0$ uniformly.

Hwever $f_n$ alternates between having no zeroes and infinite zeroes, so there is no such $N$ as postulated in the question.